# Java convert to hex vs Python convert to hex

Tags: java, python, hex

I am trying to convert some code from Python to java. 
One thing the code is doing is converting numbers to hexadecimal. But when i look at the result in java. It is not the same as in Python.

Either i am doing something wrong in my code or there is a difference in converting in java vs in python. If there is a difference in conversion. Could someone tell me what i need to do so the java application can convert in the same way

**JAVA**:

```
Integer.toHexString(tempString.charAt(d));
```

**Python**:

```
hex(ord(d)).replace("0x","")
```

**More info**

It reads a file that i don't know the data inside. Just what the result is suppose to be

Result from java is:

```
11FFFD
```

Result from python is:

```
11E37B
```

Comment: You need to post a little more information. How are the results not similar? Post the output of both operations.

Comment: I think I see what's wrong in here. In the Java Code, you are actually converting a `char`, while in Python code you are converting an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the inputs, it's harder to tell.  But the way it looks with the limited info currently available is that you're not accessing the same thing, at least in those code samples.

Java:

```
Integer.toHexString(tempString.charAt(d));
```

In python would be:

```
hex(ord(tempString[d])).replace('0x', '')
```

Whereas currently, you're accessing the `ord()` of the index, not the character location in the input string.

It would be worth checking your inputs, first, to ensure the issue is the conversion, rather than the inputs (which is how it appears).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mathias Cicero said, you are converting a char in Java where in Python you are converting an int.

The ord() function in python returns an int representation of the char, you need to do the same by casting the char to an int:

```
Integer.toHexString((int) tempString.charAt(d));
```